# Android | binding to an isolated process?

Tags: android

I have defined a service as follows:

```
<service
        android:name=".com.service.isolatedService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:process=":specialProcess"
        android:isolatedProcess="true"
        android:exported="false" />
```

and when i am trying to bind to this service from my application, i'm getting:

```
ClassNotFoundException: com.Application.MainApplication
```

when com.Application.MainApplication is:

```
public class MainApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this).build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);

    }
}
```

I am getting this error when i'm calling this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, isolatedService.class);
bindService(i, mConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

What am i doing wrong? can't we bind to a process that is isolated?

Is there any other way to run some code in a no permission enviroment?

Comment: what is `com.Application.MainApplication` ?

Comment: Hey, check my updated question :)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is lookin for a solution.

The way i fixed this was to disable Insta-run in the android studio.
The reason i did this is because Insta-run seems to ignore the manifest file (might be a bug? or it is just not stable enough?)